# Using Django CBV TemplateView with custom render_to_reponse

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to override the render_to_response method in TemplateView to include an additional parameter for the reponse_class for the HTTP status, but having trouble using:

```
class ErrorView(TemplateView):
    ''' Inserts http status code into response '''

    status = None

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        if self.status is None:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured("ErrorView requires definition of status")

        return super(ErrorView,self).render_to_response(context,{'status': self.status})


class Error404View(ErrorView):
    template_name = '404.html'
    status = 404
```

The render_to_response method (from TemplateResponseMixin) is defined with three parameters:

```
def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs)
```

However, when TemplateView calls it from the get method, it only passes the context:

```
return self.render_to_response(context)
```

How can I pass response_kwargs to render_to_response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create your own `ErrorTemplateView` and override `get` method. Since you cannot reuse `get` method from `TemplateView` for your use case.

```
class ErrorTemplateView(TemplateView):
    status = None

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.status is None:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured("ErrorTemplateView requires definition of status")

        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return self.render_to_response(context, status=self.status)
```

By the way if you need to customize error views, did you check this from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/views/#error-views)?

Comment: Thanks, Gabriel.  I guess I don't understand the dictionary as parameter construct.  I tried supplying a dictionary, and sending back a response_kwargs parameter with no success.  Didn't try the obvious of sending the status value.  

Always learning!